# opencart asks me to login again when i use the image manager

Tags: opencart

I've been running open cart on my server for a client, but it's acting rather strange. when we try to access the images to attach to a product, we get this this login image inside the 'image manager' pop up window. and the buttons to Rename, new folder and so on change color.

I can't seem to find anything on google, have you seen this before or have any idea if i got hacked or something happened?

I'm running version 1.5.6.3

[image]

After i click to add ANY image it adds that login segment. and I can try to log in, but I haven't tried.

[image]

This is the way it pops up first, THEN it turns into the image above.
This is the correct way it should stay.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem here. It used to work properly for more than a year and it stopped working days ago, without changes or updates to my website. What hosting company are you on? I'm on Bluehost, trying to understand if they changed something...

EDIT: ok I've found a solution here: http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=161&t=93875&start=40

I've created a vqmod file called fix-image-manager.xml and put it in /vqmod/xml, as suggested in that post. This is the content of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modification>
    <id>IMAGE MANAGER FIX</id>
    <version>1.5.6.1</version>
    <vqmver required="true">2.5.0</vqmver>
    <author>OpenCart</author>
    <file name="admin/view/template/common/filemanager.tpl">
      <operation>
         <search position="replace"><![CDATA[&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&image=' + encodeURIComponent('data/' + $(element).find('input[name=\'image\']').attr('value'))]]></search>
         <add><![CDATA[&image=' + encodeURIComponent('data/' + $(element).find('input[name=\'image\']').attr('value'))+'&token=<?php echo $token; ?>']]></add>
      </operation>
   </file>
   <file name="admin/view/template/catalog/*">
      <operation>
         <search position="replace"><![CDATA[&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&image=' + encodeURIComponent($('#' + field).attr('value'))]]></search>
         <add><![CDATA[&image=' + encodeURIComponent($('#' + field).attr('value')) + '&token=<?php echo $token; ?>']]></add>
      </operation>
   </file>
</modification>
```

If you don't use vqmod, you should just edit admin/view/template/common/filemanager.tpl and change this line:

```
'index.php?route=common/filemanager/image&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&image=' + encodeURIComponent('data/' + $(element).find('input[name=\'image\']').attr('value')),
```

to this:

```
'index.php?route=common/filemanager/image&image=' + encodeURIComponent('data/' + $(element).find('input[name=\'image\']').attr('value'))+'&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
```

and do the same thing in all the files in admin/view/template/catalog/ where the same line is present.

Apparently the &token should be the last parameter. I still can't get why it has worked properly so far and suddenly it stopped working.

Comment: Thank you so much. just by changing that line of code in the file you've mention I was able to get it to work in no time.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking your tokens that are in the address bar of the iframe for the image adding screen, when the tokens are incorrect this problem happens. It is because the system looks at you as a non logged in user. 
Go to the file manager page directly from your browser when you logged in to the backend to see if it exists and navigates to correctly.

```
index.php?route=common/filemanager
```

**Remember to leave the token part in your address bar and just change the above**
If it navigates to this page correctly then you will have to find the link to the image iframe and compare the tokens to the ones you are logged in with (see browser address). If it doesn't navigate to this page correctly then you will have to look at the coding for that specific page.

Comment: Hi Sphinx, yeah when i navigate to that filemanager page i still get the same error, where the buttons come up with a weird background image, and it tells me to log in. 
So i guess i need to find that file in the system and then compare it to a brand enw file from a working system, see if there are any  differences?

Comment: Yes you are correct, download the files for the same version of opencart and compare the files. Chances are the error will be in the `common` folder or `system > library`. Check the error log for any errors or enable errors and then view the page, this should help you pinpoint the issue

Comment: Its so Strange but i did a fresh install from opencart, and in the newly added open cart with the default configurations and default computer images that it comes with. I tried it and it gave me the same error. Do you think there's any chance it's related to the server i have it on? I can't think of any other reason why it would behave that way if I did a fresh install on it.

Comment: It has to do with the permissions that are set on the server. Check your files and folders permissions to make sure they correct. Permissions get applied by some servers by default. SO this is your best bet